# What data can we get from socialite?

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm using socialite laravel. What data can we get from socialite? Can we get location, phone, etc data from socialite?

Answer (score 0):

according this [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite), you can retrieve this user details :

```
    // for All Providers
$user->getId();
$user->getNickname();
$user->getName();
$user->getEmail();
$user->getAvatar();
```